# PHPEclipse & XDebug script debugging

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, xdebug, phpeclipse

I am trying to get XDebug debugging working in PHPEclipse.

All the resources I have found on the net are centered around using a web server with remote debugging. I am trying to achieve script level debugging so no web server is involved.

I have a debug configuration setup using the "PHP XDebug Script" type, and when I run the debug option in Eclipse, PHP is executing the script and output is sent to the console generated by the script.

What is wrong however, is the debugger is not stopping on any breakpoints that I add to the file in Eclipse. They are being skipped. How do I make the breakpoints work?

PHP & XDebug versions installed:

PHP 5.3.10 (cli) (built: Feb  2 2012 22:12:16) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans

I have not added any additional configuration options for XDebug within PHP. Whilst I have tried adding remote debugging options to see if that solves the problem, I assume all remote debugging options at this point are not relevant for doing localised script debugging so removed them again (and it didn't fix the problem anyway).

I am using Eclipse version 3.7.1 R3_7_1. on Fedora 16, 64bit.

Comment: The remote parameters ARE required for script level debugging. I found a tool that is part of the xdebug package debugclient that provides a simple testing interface for the DBGp protocol. The parameters are essentially required regardless of how the PHP script is executed. What is happening in the process is that the script starts xdebug, which connects over TCP/IP to the debugger in order to start debugging - confusing terminology. My IDE is still not stopping at breakpoints however. I'm guessing it has something to do with session keys, though oddly I never had to do this with Komodo.

Comment: After a great deal of time messing around, including trying Zend Studio on trial, I have managed to get breakpoints working. The solution it seems was to delete every reminiscence of an Eclipse configuration file and directory that ever existed from my system.